# Is it possible to add MatTooltip on a DOM element after the view is rendered?

Tags: angular, angular-material, fullcalendar

I would like to use  `Angular Material Tooltip` on `fullcalendar` events. But it is not possible directly since the DOMs on which it should be added on, are inside the `fullcalendar` opening and closing tags and so are not accessible before they are rendered. Is it possible to add `MatTooltip directives` after the view is rendered?

Is something like this possible in `fullcalendar`'s `onEventRenderer` callback?

```
onEventRenderer(info) {
const element = info.el;

// add MatTooltip to the element here

}
```

Comment: rather than adding tooltip dynamically you can use with ngIf and hide show

Comment: how can I use ngIf? as I said, I am trying to add it on an element that I do not have access to before it is rendered